# Unable to get fql query data to my database

Tags: php, mysql, database, facebook, facebook-fql

I am creating a website that gets events and all other event-related data from Facebook via a Facebook FQL query. Everything was working fine until I wanted to get all the queried information to my database.  Some events are recorded to the database and some are not.

Here is an example page where I put two FQL queries that will be echoed also on the page (so that means the query is successful) and they will be also inserted into database, but only one of them gets recorded. A place called HETK is recorded but Muusika Lounge is not. [Here's an example page.](http://t2na.ee/getTallinn1.php)

My second problem is that the recorded events are not recorded from today's date. Everything starts recording from tomorrow's date. (This can be seen on the picture)

The code `getTallinn1.php`:

```
$today = date("Y-m-d");

$now= $today ;         

$Muusikalounge  =   array(
'method'    => 'fql.query',
'query'     => "SELECT name, start_time,description, location,attending_count,venue,pic_cover,eid
        FROM event WHERE eid IN ( SELECT eid FROM event_member WHERE uid = 450415438376448 AND        start_time >= '$now'   )
        ORDER BY start_time asc LIMIT 0, 3",);
$Result   =   $facebook->api($Muusikalounge);
foreach ( $Result as $rows ) {
mysqli_query( $con, "REPLACE INTO tallinn (name, start_time, description, location,     attending_count, venue, pic_cover, eid) VALUES ( '".$rows['name']."', '".$rows['start_time']."',     '".$rows['description']."', '".$rows['location']."', '".$rows['attending_count']."',    '".$rows['venue']."', '".$rows ['pic_cover']['source']."', '".$rows['eid']."' )" );
}               


 $hetk  =   array(
'method'    => 'fql.query',
'query'     => "SELECT name, start_time,description, location,attending_count,venue,pic_cover,eid
            FROM event WHERE eid IN ( SELECT eid FROM event_member WHERE uid = 282875915182473 AND     start_time >= '$now'   )
           ORDER BY start_time asc LIMIT 0, 3",);       

$Result1   =   $facebook->api($hetk);
foreach ( $Result1 as $rows1 ) {
  mysqli_query( $con, "REPLACE INTO tallinn (name, start_time, description, location,     attending_count, venue, pic_cover, eid) VALUES ( '".$rows1['name']."', '".$rows1['start_time']."',      '".$rows1['description']."', '".$rows1['location']."', '".$rows1['attending_count']."',     '".$rows1['venue']."', '".$rows1 ['pic_cover']['source']."', '".$rows1['eid']."' )" );
}
```

Here's the recorded data in PHPMyAdmin:

[database http://t2na.ee/database.jpg](http://t2na.ee/database.jpg)

The queries are identical. I have no clue what might be the cause here.

**UPDATE**

I found a clue to this problem.
Leaving out Description insertion to the database fixes the problem. Now everything works as expected. But I cannot figure out what is the difference between some of the event description strings that are causing this conflict here. The description strings taken from events differ only for their lenght but the lenght doesn't seem to be the problem here also. I changed the description type to LongText, still the same problem.

Comment: You neglected to escape/handle the data that you put into the queries properly. Go read up on the topic of SQL Injection.

Answer (score 0):

For the date issue, use the FQL `now()` function instead of your own date string. Facebook assumes a timezone of `America/Los_Angeles` if one isn't specified, so your `$now` may be interpreted as tomorrow by FQL.

For the data not writing, what happens if you comment out the `mysqli_query` for `$hetk`? I'm wondering if the two queries are overwriting each other in your database somehow.

Finally, with the sunset of FQL looming, you should be writing new Facebook API calls using pure Graph API.

Comment: I tried the now() function, but still same result. It wouldn't make sense either because on the page it echoes also today's events.  
   
I also tried commenting out mysqli_query for $hetk, then nothing was recorded in the database.

But will the FQL be shut down for good? Graph API doesn't have nearly as much advantages as FQL, they can't just shut it down, can they?

Comment: Hmmm. There is something wrong with your mysqli queries then.  Facebook can and has shut down lots of things. Since f8, Facebook is at least promising to be nice about it and not just "disappearing" an endpoint like they have in the past. Official notice is here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog/#v2_0_fql

Comment: The query error could be a mismatched quote issue. Since your query is a double quoted string, you can use [curly syntax](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex) for your variables: `VALUES ( '{$rows['name']}', '{$rows['start_time']}', ...`. Better still might be [`sprintf()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php)

Comment: I tried using curly syntax  `VALUES ( '{$rows['name']}', '{$rows['start_time']}', ... `, still the same issue, one gets into the  DB other not.